# Correct way to inherit from a virtual class with non-virtual parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

I've written this test code that uses three types: `struct One` is a normal type with no virtual  members, `struct Two : One` has a pure virtual function and a virtual destructor, and `struct Three : Two` implements `Two`'s interface.

```
#include <iostream>

struct One
{
    ~One() {
        std::cout << "~One()\n";
    }
};

struct Two : One
{
    virtual ~Two() {
        std::cout << "~Two()\n";
    }

    virtual void test() = 0;
};

struct Three : Two
{
    virtual ~Three() {
        std::cout << "~Three()\n";
    }

    virtual void test() {
        std::cout << "Three::test()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Two* two = new Three;
    two->test();

    One* one = two;
    delete one;
}
```

Unsurprisingly, [the output was](http://ideone.com/kj4Us) this:

> Three::test()
>   ~One()

Is there any way to fix this other than making every destructor virtual? Or should programmers just be careful not to run into this situation? I find it odd that there's no warning when compiling this.

Comment: An easy fix: Use private or protected inheritance from `One` and expose functionality through using declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "fix" is not to delete the objects through a pointer to `One`.

If this is a frequent problem, or not, depends on how your classes are used. For example, the standard library contains structs like `unary_function` without a virtual destructor, but we hardly ever see it misused like this.

Comment: and to enforce that, the destructor of `One` should be protected

Answer (score 2):

`delete one` invokes undefined behaviour, because the dynamic type of the object does not match the static type, and the static type does not have a virtual destructor.

The usual way to avoid problems like this is to make destructors be either public and virtual, or protected and non-virtual (on classes that are expected to be used in this way).

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful and make One's destructor virtual. Some compilers do warn about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want working destructors in derived classes then you must define them as virtual. It is the only way.