# Correct way to inherit from a virtual class with non-virtual parent continued

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

My question is building on this question: [Correct way to inherit from a virtual class with non-virtual parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769259/correct-way-to-inherit-from-a-virtual-class-with-non-virtual-parent).

Is my understanding right that in the case which is described in the question, the Three and Two part of new allocated object are leaking because they are not destructed?

Source:

```
#include <iostream>

struct One
{
    ~One() {
        std::cout << "~One()\n";
    }
};

struct Two : One
{
    virtual ~Two() {
        std::cout << "~Two()\n";
    }

    virtual void test() = 0;
};

struct Three : Two
{
    virtual ~Three() {
        std::cout << "~Three()\n";
    }

    virtual void test() {
        std::cout << "Three::test()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Two* two = new Three;
    two->test();

    One* one = two;
    delete one;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764353/what-does-has-virtual-method-but-non-virtual-destructor-warning-mean-durin/8764393#8764393) yesterday.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the context, so that we don't need to follow the link to know what "two" and "three" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The definition of a memory leak is a situation where you are unable to delete something that you created (and whose lifetime you are therefore responsible for managing).

As the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769371/366904) to that question indicate, `delete one` invokes undefined behavior (which in most cases will probably translate to a regular old memory leak, but things could be as bad as [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)) because the runtime type of the specified object does not match its static (declared) type, and the static type does not have a virtual destructor.

The applicable section from the C++ standard is this one:

> §5.3.5/3: In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

The solution is either to declare all of the destructors `virtual`, or not to delete the objects through a pointer to `One`.